# Need help is getting the substring

Tags: vba, excel

I am having string in format

```
"<testname>$ns1$,$NS2$,$NS3$</testname>"
```

and i need to get the string as `"$ns1$,$NS2$,$NS3$"`

there may be possibility of geeting string as

```
"    <testname>$ns1$,$NS2$,$NS3$</testname>"
```

Thanks in advance
Excel Dev

Comment: your question is not clear..what is the original string and what are you looking for in it(substring).

Comment: i do not know how sting is not seen correctly there Orignal String is "<testname>$ns1$,$NS2$,$NS3$</testname>"

Comment: do I understand correctly: you have a string sourrounded by HTML like tags in an EXCEL cell and you want to remove the tags to get only the "inside" ?

Comment: yes you are correct Mike

Comment: I sincerely hope you're not trying to write your own code to parse XML... that would be some serious wheel reinvention.

Answer (score 0):

So to reformulate your problem, you want to cut out a substring starting after the first ">" and ending before the first "

Before we go to VBA let's try to find a formula

```
cell [A1] contains text "<tag>Content</tag>"
```

so

```
   Formula                            Result      Comment
1) =FIND(">",A1,1)+1                  6           1st char of inner
2) =FIND("</",A1)-1                   12          last char of inner
3) =FIND("</",A1)-FIND(">",A1,1)-1    7           length of inner
```

combining 1 & 3 you get

```
4) =MID(A1,FIND(">",A1,1)+1,FIND("</",A1)-FIND(">",A1;1)-1)
                                      Content     the inner
```

meaning that you can cut out the inner without VBA ..... but we sure can provide brilliant VBA as well :-))

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetInnerTag(byval value as string) as string
   dim offset1 as integer
   dim offset2 as integer
   offset1= instr(1,value,">")
   'If the index of the first greater-than
   'is less than one, return an empty string
   if offset1 <1 then
      GetInnerTag=""
      Exit Function
   end if

   offset2=instr(offset1+1,value,"<")

   'If the index of the first less-than 
   'less than one, return ""
   if offset2 <1 then
      GetInnerTag=""
      Exit Function
   end if
   GetInnerTag=mid(value,offset1+1,(offset2-offset1-1))
End Function
```